# UDP Port Forwarding and outgoing port

Tags: router, nat, udp

For UDP, assume that an incoming port (say X) is forwarded onto a port on a local host (say Y). Does that guarantee that any outgoing traffic from port Y from the local host appears as traffic from port X for other external hosts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "a local host" I presume you don't mean the local host (the machine doing the forwarding), but something on the LAN.

In any case, the answer is no, you can't count on anything with most NATs when it comes to the source port for egress traffic (traffic initiated from inside the LAN).

Response traffic (e.g. responses to externally-initiated / forwarded traffic) back to the same peer that initiated the redirection will have that source port, but generally not traffic to other peers.

Some NATs (such as our product [WinGate](http://www.wingate.com) will keep the same source port as the internal client if possible, but this port is potentially conflicted amongst other LAN clients accessing the same peer IP:port.

I don't know of any that would map the outbound source port based on an incoming redirect configuration.

Disclaimer: I work for Qbik who are the authors of WinGate

Comment: That answers my question. Thanks. Nice to get a feedback from writers of  commercial software.